# Angular application is not accessible using full path url opened in new tab (base url +component path ) deployed in kubernetes (k8s) using nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes, angular-ui-router

Angular application has following paths,

- https://base-path.com
- https://base-path.com/dashboard

Using localhost I can access http://localhost/dashboard directly in new tab but same is not working when accessed by app hosted in kubernetes (k8s).
am deploying the app in k8s(deployment and service) and using ingress to define path like below,

```
paths:
    - path: /
      pathType: Prefix
    - path: /
      pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Getting 404 not found error like below when accessed by path in new tab (https://base-path.com/dashboard).

However I can access the base url (https://base-path.com ) and clicking on the button in the landing UI page to redirect to other component works fine (same tab in browser - https://base-path.com/dashboard)

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks